# How to keep the same width for columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there any way to wrap the long text 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' and allow it to be multi-line for keeping the same width for columns?

The width of .menu must be as long as possible!!

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 300px;
}
.menu {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    border: 1px solid #CC6699;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>    
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>    
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>    
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;`

EDIT: I've done it in the first two divs

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 300px;
}
.menu {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    border: 1px solid #CC6699;
}
.inner {
    width: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;/* using this and the width */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="menu"><div class="inner">aaaaa</div></div>
    <div class="menu"><div class="inner">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>    
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>    
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>    
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="menu">aaaaa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But the width of .menu must be as long as possible. I forgot to mention about it...sorry.

Comment: Ah ok. Then add a container in each `.menu` then you add a fixed width and the word wrap to the inner container, leaving the `.menu` the same.

Comment: Adding fixed width can't be a solution.... .menu is flexible, so its container must be flexible.

Comment: What I was saying is that you keep the `.menu` width flexible but you add another element inside `.menu` which will encapsulate the *aaaa*'s and have a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `width` to your CSS for `.menu` and also add `word-wrap:break-word;` See below:

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 300px;
}
.menu {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    border: 1px solid #CC6699;
    width:100px; /*change this as necessary*/
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf0p8gwx/)